# Drupal Translated Taxonomy Terms only appear in the default language?

Tags: drupal, autocomplete, internationalization, drupal-7, taxonomy

I have a problem with Drupal translated taxonomy terms. The terms are translated just fine using the i18n module. However, when I want to view the terms while creating a new node (autocomplete field) or by creating a view for the taxonomy terms, the terms are only viewed in the default site language. Did anyone experience this problem? Does anyone have a solution?

I am using drupal 7 with the latest version of i18n module.

Thanks!

Comment: While saving a node and some new taxonomy terms via a autocomplete field, the new taxonomy terms are saved using the default language of the site instead of the language of the node that is being saved.